# argument must be a string or unicode object: got tuple instead

Tags: arguments

The following below is the actual code:
**I get the following error: TypeError: list indices must be

integers or slices, not str and TypeError: argument 1 must be a

string or unicode object: got list instead**

```
def search(gss=None, description=None, postcode=None):
if request.method == "POST":
postcodevar = request.form['postcodevar']

print("Asssigning SQl statement to a postgreSQL variable")
postgreSQL_select_Query_2 = [("""SELECT DISTINCT gss,description,
postcode FROM postcodelatlng pt, gss.shapes g 
WHERE st_contains(geom,pos) AND %(postcode)s~* '(\y(?:[A-PR-    
UWYZ](?:[A-HK-]?\d{1,2}|d[A-HJKMNP-Y]|[A-HK-Y]\d[ABEHMNPRV-
Y]))(?:\s*\d[ABD-HJLNP-UW-]{2})\y)' 
LIMIT 50""", {'postcode': postcodevar})]

cursor.execute(postgreSQL_select_Query_2, postcodevar)
print("Selecting rows from mobile table using  
cursor.fetchall")
records = cursor.fetchall()
return render_template('idm_prototype.html', data=records)



File "/Users/fernandocamutari/PycharmProjects/DeploymentPrototype/main.py", line 69, in search

                                         WHERE st_contains(geom,pos)

        AND %(postcode)s~* '(\y(?:[A-PR-UWYZ](?:[A-HK-]?\d{1,2}|d[A-HJKMNP-Y]|[A-HK-Y]\d[ABEHMNPRV-Y]))(?:\s*\d[ABD-HJLNP-UW-]{2})\y)'

                LIMIT 50""", {'postcode': postcodevar})]

        cursor.execute(postgreSQL_select_Query_2)

        print("Selecting rows from mobile table using cursor.fetchall")

  records = cursor.fetchall()

  return render_template('idm_prototype.html', data=records)


TypeError: argument 1 must be a string or unicode object: got list instead
```

This is the Copy/Paste friendly version of the traceback.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/fernandocamutari/PycharmProjects/DeploymentPrototype/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2088, in **call**
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/Users/fernandocamutari/PycharmProjects/DeploymentPrototype/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "/Users/fernandocamutari/PycharmProjects/DeploymentPrototype/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2070, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/Users/fernandocamutari/PycharmProjects/DeploymentPrototype/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1515, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/Users/fernandocamutari/PycharmProjects/DeploymentPrototype/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1513, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/Users/fernandocamutari/PycharmProjects/DeploymentPrototype/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1499, in dispatch_request
return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
File "/Users/fernandocamutari/PycharmProjects/DeploymentPrototype/main.py", line 54, in search
postgreSQL_select_Query_2 = {"""SELECT DISTINCT gss, description,
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Comment: Can you please add your code?

Comment: I have added the code at the top..

Comment: Please post the full traceback error

Comment: TypeError: argument 1 must be a string or unicode object: got list instead

Comment: TypeError: argument 1 must be a string or unicode object: got list instead

Comment: This is not the **full** traceback error bro.

Comment: Thats all I get from the trace back...

Comment: Are you not able to look at the code based on the error message above and see ifou can identify the issue?